# Is there any way to find common rows between two files where one file has two column and other has 1 column? Files are huge, cannot work in R

Tags: linux, grep

I have two files in Linux
One file has two columns and 300million rows , the other file has one column and 1498  rows (SNPs rs IDs from HG19).

The first file looks like this below. The first column has coordinates and have colons in between the corrdinates values (1:10019:TA:T), the second column has IDs (rs775809821)

```
1:10019:TA:T    rs775809821

1:10039:A:C     rs978760828

1:10043:T:A     rs1008829651

1:10051:A:G     rs1052373574

1:10055:T:A     rs892501864

1:10055:T:TA    rs768019142

1:10165:A:AC    rs796884232
```

The second file has only one column and looks like this

```
rs11234969

rs372076

rs10417746

rs2476601

rs10760127
```

I want to match the values from second file to those in first file so I can have a final file that has all possible rows from file two and their coordinates  from file 1.

I have tried  'grep' and awk but no success.

```
       grep -F file1.txt file2.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1 > grep.txt
```

The final file should have all the possible IDs (rs.....) that are common in both files with the coordinates too.

Comment: In your sample data, none of `rs` values from `file2` are available in `file1`

Comment: The second file is tiny and easily fits in RAM.  I recommend perl for this task but the same approach will work in any language.  1. Read the second file into an associative array  2. Loop through rows in the large file, splitting each row into columns.  For each row where the ID column is present in the associative array, print the row.  In perl this would be about 7 or 8 lines of code total even if you don't use the trailing-if idiom.

Answer (score 0):

This will output ID per file, eg: `rs11234969.txt`, `rs372076.txt`, etc. Every file contains corrdinates and ID like format of file one.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    awk -v line=$line '{if($2==line)print $0}' one.txt >${line}.txt
done <two.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the command to make things right:

```
grep -wnF -f file2.txt file1.txt > grep.txt
```

The output will contain the line number in the file `file1.txt`, followed by a colon and the corresponding line.

Note that this requires that the `file2.txt` does not contain blank lines, and the lines are not surrounded by spaces or other blank/hidden symbols.
If some of the above conditions are not true, use the following:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*\([^ \t]*\)[ \t]*$/\1/; /^[ \t]*$/d' file2.txt | \
  grep -wnF -f /dev/stdin file1.txt > grep.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if none of the IDs feature in the coordinates.  So your own approach was fairly close, I'd just suggest a minor change.

```
grep -f file2 file1 > new_file
```

The thing is that you **really** don't want to use the file w/ 300 million rows as the pattern file, firstly because it has the extra data (coordinates) that will never match, but also because of its size.